# How to increase the number of PCIe slots available?

Tags: pci-express

I have a motherboard with a single PCIe3x16 slot. Currently it has a GeForce 1060 card plugged into it. I would like to add an additional PCIe3x4 device, an Optane SSD with a PCIe3x4 interface to my system. Is it possible?

I don't seem to find any PCIe expansion solution that expands a single PCIe3x16 slot to multiple such slots, that also supports graphic cards.

How can I increase the number of PCIe slots available?

Comment: Buy a motherboard that conforms to your requirements.

Comment: @Ron Maupin That's exactly what I would like to avoid.

Comment: You will need a new motherboard and possibly case as well... Or look at a different solution to add an SSD, on a SATA connector perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for your recommendations. Indeed, simply replacing the motherboard would be the cheapest solution for this use case. However:

- My motherboard ain't broke so I won't fix it. There is a certain risk associated 
  with disassembling and reassembling the system, including moving over the CPU, 
  and the memory sticks to the other motherboard.
- Replacing the motherboard also creates problems associated with software licenses 
  that bind the software to the motherboard.

The number of PCIe slots can be increased by using PCIe splitters readily available from multiple manufacturers. Some PCIex16 splitters with GPU support:

[GPU-Oriented x4 PCIe 4-Way Splitter](https://amfeltec.com/gpu-oriented-x4-pcie-4-way-splitter/)

[PCIe x16 Gen 3 Host Target Kit (3811)](https://www.onestopsystems.com/product/pcie-x16-gen-3-host-target-kit-3811)

Comment: You need to understand these PCI-E splitters aren't adding extra lanes of bandwidth, so you'll be halving the bandwidth to your gfx card, and giving your optane drive half the b/w it expects. This 'might' work. It might even work reasonably well. But more likely it'll cause problems somewhere down the line.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. The bandwidth will not increase. I understand, that the Optane will share 4 lanes out of 16 with the GPU card.

Comment: What software are you using that licenses to the main board? Are you talking about the OS? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Because the PCI slots have to correspond to cut-outs in the case, it is difficult-to-impossible to find a solution that will split your PCI lanes.

Even though you're still only looking for a single external PCI device, and the other lanes will be used got a storage device, if you look at the main board and the case, you'll notice there are only limited ways that an add-on decide could offer the functions you're imagining.

It is also likely to be cheaper to buy an entirely new main board with the features you want.

While you may not WANT to buy a new main board, what you want doesn't win against what's possible in this specific situation.